# How to get pixel information inside a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my fragment shader I can load a texture, then do this:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main(void) {
   vec4 color = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
   gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

That sets the current pixel to color value of texture. I can modify these, etc and it works well.

But a few questions.  How do I tell "which" pixel I am?  For example, say I want to set pixel 100,100 (x,y) to red.  Everything else to black.  How do I do a :

"if currentSelf.Position() == (100,100); then color=red; else color=black?"

?

I know how to set colors, but how do I get "my" location?

Secondly, how do I get values from a neighbor pixel?

I tried this:

```
vec4 nextColor = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[1].st);
```

But not clear what it is returning?  if I'm pixel 100,100; how do I get the values from 101,100 or 100,101?

Answer (score 38):

> How do I tell "which" pixel I am?

You're not a pixel. You're a *fragment*. There's a reason that OpenGL calls them "Fragment shaders"; it's because they aren't pixels *yet*. Indeed, not only may they never become pixels (via `discard` or depth tests or whatever), thanks to multisampling, multiple fragments can combine to form a *single* pixel.

If you want to tell where your fragment shader is in window-space, use [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml). Fragment positions are floating-point values, not integers, so you have to test with a range instead of a single "100, 100" value.

> Secondly, how do I get values from a neighbor pixel?

If you're talking about the neighboring framebuffer pixel, you *don't*. Fragment shaders cannot arbitrarily read from the framebuffer, either in their own position or in a neighboring one.

If you're talking about accessing a neighboring *texel* from the one you accessed, then that's just a matter of biasing the texture coordinate you pass to `texture2D`. You have to get the size of the texture (since you're not using GLSL 1.30 or above, you have to manually pass this in), invert the size and either add or subtract these sizes from the S and T component of the texture coordinate.

Comment: Beat me to it; all I had to say that differs even slightly from this was the link http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_FragCoord.xml that goes into slightly more detail on `gl_FragCoord` and the recommendation of an intermediate render to texture if he really wants to compute output fragments based on the combination of multiple neighbouring pixels in what is otherwise the output buffer.

Comment: Basically what I want to do, is if pixel x,y has neighbors with red in them, to increase red in x,y.  Is there a tutorial that would explain how to do this?

Comment: @user697111: You want to implement a "dilation" filter working on the red channel of a texture. Google those keywords and you should find plenty.

Comment: @XStylish: No, it isn't. I don't see [any notice in this section that `gl_FragCoord` is compatibility-only](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#built-in-language-variables). All the compatibility stuff is in section 7.1.7, while `gl_FragCoord` is in 7.1.5.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's great! I didn't check the official Khronos page but some forum post I saw there earlier was confusing that it sounded like it's deprecated so btw thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 7):

Easy peasy.

Just compute the size of a pixel based on resolution. Then look up +1 and -1.

```
vec2 onePixel = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / u_textureSize;
gl_FragColor = (
   texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord) +
   texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + vec2(onePixel.x, 0.0)) +
   texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + vec2(-onePixel.x, 0.0))) / 3.0;
```

There's a good example [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html)