# How to color individual pixels with OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vertices

Is there possible to change the color of an individual pixel with OpenGL ES 2.0? Right now, I have found that I can manage that using a vertex. I've used this method to draw it:

```java
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
```

The size of the point was set to minimum in order to be a single pixel painted.

All good, until I've needed to draw 3 to 4 millions of them! It takes 5-6 seconds to initialize only one frame. This is time-inefficient as long as the pixels will be updated constantly. The update/ refresh would be preferable to be as close as possible to 60 fps.

How can I paint them in a more efficient way?

**Note:** It's a must to paint them individually only!

My attempt is here (for a screen of 1440x2560 px):

```
package com.example.ctelescu.opengl_pixel_draw;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;


public class PixelDrawRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

  private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];

  private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

  private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

  private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

  private final FloatBuffer mVerticesBuffer;

  private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

  private int mPositionHandle;

  private int mColorHandle;

  private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4;

  private final int mStrideBytes = 7 * mBytesPerFloat;

  private final int mPositionOffset = 0;

  private final int mPositionDataSize = 3;

  private final int mColorOffset = 3;

  private final int mColorDataSize = 4;


  public PixelDrawRenderer() {
    // Define the vertices.

//    final float[] vertices = {
//        // X, Y, Z,
//        // R, G, B, A
//        -1f, 1f, 0.0f,
//        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
//
//        -0.9f, 1.2f, 0.0f,
//        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
//
//        -0.88f, 1.2f, 0.0f,
//        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
//
//        -0.87f, 1.2f, 0.0f,
//        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
//
//        -0.86f, 1.2f, 0.0f,
//        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
//
//        -0.85f, 1.2f, 0.0f,
//        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

    // Initialize the buffers.
    mVerticesBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(22579200 * mBytesPerFloat)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

//    mVerticesBuffer.put(vertices);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background clear color to gray.
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    // Position the eye behind the origin.
    final float eyeX = 0.0f;
    final float eyeY = 0.0f;
    final float eyeZ = 1.5f;

    // We are looking toward the distance
    final float lookX = 0.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = -5.0f;

    // Set our up vector. This is where our head would be pointing were we holding the camera.
    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;

    // Set the view matrix. This matrix can be said to represent the camera position.
    // NOTE: In OpenGL 1, a ModelView matrix is used, which is a combination of a model and
    // view matrix. In OpenGL 2, we can keep track of these matrices separately if we choose.
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

    final String vertexShader =
        "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"    // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.

            + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"    // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
            + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n"    // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.

            + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"    // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

            + "void main()                    \n"    // The entry point for our vertex shader.
            + "{                              \n"
            + "   v_Color = a_Color;          \n"    // Pass the color through to the fragment shader.
            // It will be interpolated across the vertex.
            + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix   \n"    // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
            + "               * a_Position;   \n"    // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in
            + "   gl_PointSize = 0.1;         \n"
            + "}                              \n";   // normalized screen coordinates.

    final String fragmentShader =
        "#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH    \n"
            + "precision highp float;         \n"
            + "#else                          \n"
            + "precision mediump float;       \n"    // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a
            // precision in the fragment shader.
            + "#endif                         \n"

            + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"    // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the
            // vertex per fragment.

            + "void main()                    \n"    // The entry point for our fragment shader.
            + "{                              \n"
            + "   gl_FragColor = v_Color;     \n"    // Pass the color directly through the pipeline.
            + "}                              \n";

    // Load in the vertex shader.
    int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    if (vertexShaderHandle != 0) {
      // Pass in the shader source.
      GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShader);

      // Compile the shader.
      GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);

      // Get the compilation status.
      final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
      GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

      // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
      if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderHandle);
        vertexShaderHandle = 0;
      }
    }

    if (vertexShaderHandle == 0) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader.");
    }

    // Load in the fragment shader shader.
    int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    if (fragmentShaderHandle != 0) {
      // Pass in the shader source.
      GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShader);

      // Compile the shader.
      GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

      // Get the compilation status.
      final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
      GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

      // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
      if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
        fragmentShaderHandle = 0;
      }
    }

    if (fragmentShaderHandle == 0) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader.");
    }

    // Create a program object and store the handle to it.
    int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    if (programHandle != 0) {
      // Bind the vertex shader to the program.
      GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);

      // Bind the fragment shader to the program.
      GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

      // Bind attributes
      GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
      GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "a_Color");

      // Link the two shaders together into a program.
      GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);

      // Get the link status.
      final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
      GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

      // If the link failed, delete the program.
      if (linkStatus[0] == 0) {
        GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
        programHandle = 0;
      }
    }

    if (programHandle == 0) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
    }

    // Set program handles. These will later be used to pass in values to the program.
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Color");

    // Tell OpenGL to use this program when rendering.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
    // Set the OpenGL viewport to the same size as the surface.
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the same
    // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1.0f;
    final float far = 10.0f;

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

    float[] vertices = new float[22579200];
    int counter = 0;

    for (float i = -width / 2; i < width / 2; i++) {
      for (float j = height / 2; j > -height / 2; j--) {
        // Initialize the buffers.
        vertices[counter++] = 2f * i * (1f / width);    //X
        vertices[counter++] = 2f * j * (1.5f / height);    //Y
        vertices[counter++] = 0;    //Z
        vertices[counter++] = 1f;   //blue
        vertices[counter++] = 1f;   //green
        vertices[counter++] = 0f;   //blue
        vertices[counter++] = 1f;   //alpha
      }
    }

    mVerticesBuffer.put(vertices);
    mVerticesBuffer.clear();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw the vertices facing straight on.
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    drawVertices(mVerticesBuffer);
  }

  private void drawVertices(final FloatBuffer aVertexBuffer) {
    // Pass in the position information
    aVertexBuffer.position(mPositionOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        mStrideBytes, aVertexBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Pass in the color information
    aVertexBuffer.position(mColorOffset);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, mColorDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        mStrideBytes, aVertexBuffer);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);

    // This multiplies the view matrix by the model matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which currently contains model * view).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

    // This multiplies the modelview matrix by the projection matrix, and stores the result in the MVP matrix
    // (which now contains model * view * projection).
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, 3225600);
  }
}
```

Comment: Draw a single triangle large enough to cover the entire screen, and compute the color in the shader.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I need to manipulate pixels individually. Each pixel color will be an output from an algorithm, so I can't predict the color in order to apply a polygon or other primitives.

Comment: What stops you from putting that algorithm into the fragment shader?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, this is a good idea. But, how can I manipulate the color of a single pixel within a fragment shader? It is a special variable for this? I cannot found.

Comment: You write the color to `gl_FragColor`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, with gl_FragColor I understand that I can color only the fragment itself, which represents a bunch of pixels. Meanwhile, I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779415/how-to-get-pixel-information-inside-a-fragment-shader). It seems that is not possible what I want to do.

Comment: No, one fragment usually equals one pixel. Under certain conditions you can get more than 1 fragment per pixel (antialiasing), but never mutiple pixels per fragment.